# Using a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use a query to update a row of data in my database. Here is my code:

```
$query= "UPDATE users SET intro= '".$intro."', profile_pic= '".$profile_pic."' WHERE   
user_id= '".$_SESSION['id']."'";
mysqli_query= ($connect, $query);
```

But I keep getting the error on my mysqli_query line:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: php gives you a pretty good description of what is wrong. Try to look at your code more carefully before posting here.

Answer (score 3):

```
mysqli_query= ($connect, $query);
```

becomes

```
mysqli_query($connect, $query);
```

Comment: Simple mistake on my part. Thank you!

Comment: @user1592953 You should pick one answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should have

```
mysqli_query($connect, $query);
```

not

```
mysqli_query= ($connect, $query);
```